# Sending server-side events to GA4 using API / Postman

Tags: postman, server-sent-events, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to send server-side events to GA4. It's not working via PHP so I try to figure out what's wrong via Postman. But my Postman Post requests also don't get any events into GA4.

**METHOD:**

```
POST
```

**URL:**

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-<<MY ID IS HERE>>&api_secret=<<MY API SECRET IS HERE>>
```

**BODY:**

```
{
    "client id": "1234567890",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "pageview",
            "params": {
                "page_title": "TEST GA4 SERVER SIDE"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**HEADERS:**

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: ‹calculated when request is sent>
Host: ‹calculated when request is sent>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.33.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Bearer <<MY API SECRET IS HERE>>  // Tried it with and without that
```

Does anybody have any idea or hint what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Here are a few potential issues in your request that you should
   address:
2. Parameter Naming: The parameters you are using in the request body
   should follow the correct naming conventions for GA4. Specifically,
   the parameter names should use underscores _ instead of spaces.
   Also, the "client_id" should be "user_id."
3. Endpoint: Ensure that you are using the correct GA4 measurement
   endpoint for server-side events. The correct endpoint for
   measurement is usually https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect.
4. Headers: The "Content-Length" and "Host" headers should be
   calculated automatically by Postman, so you don't need to set them
   manually. Also, make sure the "Authorization" header is not required
   for GA4 server-side events.

**METHOD: POST**

**ENDPOINT:**

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-<<YOUR_MEASUREMENT_ID>>
```

**PAYLOAD:**

```
{
    "user_id": "1234567890",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "page_view",
            "params": {
                "page_title": "TEST GA4 SERVER SIDE"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: I've changed the event name from "pageview" to "page_view" to follow the GA4 naming convention.

Additionally, check if you have the necessary permissions and configurations in your GA4 property to receive server-side events.

For more : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=firebase

Comment: that unfortunately didn't work either. (your literal example). What do you mean with permissions and configurations in GA4? We created the secret API key, isn't that enough to receive these calls?

Comment: we are expected to add the Service account Email to the GA and need to give required permission to access the data from GA4